# Splitting an address into fields in SQL

Tags: sql, parsing, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code to split an address string in T-SQL. Excepting the unit number, which is already in its own field, it would affect too much of the application to split the address into different database fields. It's a bit of a long story, but it's also not possible to make it a parameterized query, or to write the equivalent application code in C#. Still, I'm curious if anyone can think of any edge case that would put things into the wrong fields.

The only case I've come across is "East End Ave", but even the US Postal Service suggests incorrectly parsing 'East' as a directional (for consistency) (reference: [very long pdf](http://pe.usps.gov/cpim/ftp/pubs/Pub28/pub28.pdf), search for 'directional', or go to page 233).

I'm only worried about Canadian and American addresses, but in Canada, French-style street types before the street name are fair game (e.g. 'Rue Montreal'). For a tie-breaker, I default to the English style (e.g. ['Rue Street'](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=rue+street) is parsed with the name 'Rue' and type 'Street').

`StreetType` and `StreetDirection` are tables which contain street types and street directions, as `TypeName`/`TypeAbbr` and `DirectionName`/`DirectionType` pairs respectively - I can post the values I've been using there if anyone's curious, but the `StreetType` is *quite* long. `StreetDirection` also includes French directions ('ouest', 'nord', 'sud', 'est', etc.), as well as their equivalents of 'northeast', 'northwest', etc.

```
DECLARE @CivicNum AS NVARCHAR(10) = ''
DECLARE @Predir AS NVARCHAR(10) = ''
DECLARE @Name AS NVARCHAR(100) = ''
DECLARE @Type AS NVARCHAR(15) = ''
DECLARE @FrenchType AS NVARCHAR(15) = ''
DECLARE @Postdir AS NVARCHAR(10) = ''

SET @Name = '123 E Fake St. S'

SET @CivicNum = SUBSTRING(@Name, 1, 1)

IF ISNUMERIC(@CivicNum) = 1
  BEGIN
    -- will assume an initial integer is a civic number
    DECLARE @LastSpace AS INTEGER
    DECLARE @NextSpace AS INTEGER

    DECLARE @Temp as VARCHAR(15)

    -- get the first token, and push it into @CivicNum
    SET @LastSpace = 1
    SET @NextSpace = CHARINDEX(' ', @Name)
    SET @CivicNum = SUBSTRING(@Name, 1, @NextSpace)

    -- get the next token, to check for a fractional @CivicNum
    SET @LastSpace = @NextSpace + 1
    SET @NextSpace = CHARINDEX(' ', @Name, @LastSpace)

    SET @Temp = SUBSTRING(@Name, @LastSpace, @NextSpace - @LastSpace)

    -- assumption: if the token contains a slash, it is a fraction
    -- for @CivicNum
    IF CHARINDEX('\\', @Temp) > 0 OR CHARINDEX ('/', @Temp) > 0
      SET @CivicNum = @CivicNum + ' ' + @Temp
    ELSE
      SET @NextSpace = @LastSpace

    -- reverse the string to extract type, direction from right
    SET @Name = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Name, @NextSpace, LEN(@Name)))

    -- get the final token, check if it is a post directional (N, S, E, W)
    SET @LastSpace = 1
    SET @NextSpace = CHARINDEX(' ', @Name)    
    SET @Temp = RTRIM(LTRIM(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Name, 1, @NextSpace))))

    -- strip period, if one exists
    IF SUBSTRING(@Temp, LEN(@Temp), 1) = '.' 
      SET @Temp = SUBSTRING(@Temp, 1, LEN(@Temp) - 1)

    -- check if it exists in the StreetDirection table
    SELECT @PostDir=DirectionAbbr FROM StreetDirection WHERE UPPER(DirectionName) LIKE UPPER(@Temp)
    IF NOT (@PostDir LIKE @Temp) -- try abbreviation
      SELECT @PostDir=DirectionAbbr FROM StreetDirection WHERE UPPER(DirectionAbbr) LIKE UPPER(@Temp)

    -- if @PostDir was found, get the next token
    IF NOT (@PostDir LIKE '') 
      BEGIN
       SET @LastSpace = @NextSpace + 1
       SET @NextSpace = CHARINDEX(' ', @Name, @LastSpace + 1)
       SET @Temp = RTRIM(LTRIM(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Name, @LastSpace, @NextSpace - @LastSpace))))
       IF SUBSTRING(@Temp, LEN(@Temp), 1) = '.' -- strip period 
          SET @Temp = SUBSTRING(@Temp, 1, LEN(@Temp) - 1)
      END

    -- check if the current token is a StreetType    
    SELECT @Type=TypeName FROM StreetType WHERE UPPER(TypeName) LIKE UPPER(@Temp)
    IF NOT (@Type LIKE @Temp) -- try abbreviation
      SELECT @Type=TypeName FROM StreetType WHERE UPPER(TypeAbbr) LIKE UPPER(@Temp)

    -- reverse address again to check for pre-directional and french street type
    IF NOT (@Type LIKE '')
      SET @LastSpace = @NextSpace + 1

    SET @Name = RTRIM(LTRIM(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Name, @LastSpace, LEN(@Name)))))

    -- get the next token, and check for a pre-directional
    SET @LastSpace = 1
    SET @NextSpace = CHARINDEX(' ', @Name)
    SET @Temp = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Name, 1, @NextSpace)))
    IF SUBSTRING(@Temp, LEN(@Temp), 1) = '.' -- strip period
      SET @Temp = SUBSTRING(@Temp, 1, LEN(@Temp) - 1)

    SELECT @PreDir=DirectionAbbr FROM StreetDirection WHERE UPPER(DirectionName) LIKE UPPER(@Temp)
    IF NOT (@PreDir LIKE @Temp) -- try abbreviation
      SELECT @PreDir=DirectionAbbr FROM StreetDirection WHERE UPPER(DirectionAbbr) LIKE UPPER(@Temp)    

    -- if a pre-directional was found, get the next token
    IF NOT (@PreDir LIKE '') 
      BEGIN
       SET @LastSpace = @NextSpace + 1
       SET @NextSpace = CHARINDEX(' ', @Name, @LastSpace + 1)
       SET @Temp = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Name, @LastSpace, LEN(@Name))))
       IF SUBSTRING(@Temp, LEN(@Temp), 1) = '.' -- strip period 
          SET @Temp = SUBSTRING(@Temp, 1, LEN(@Temp) - 1)
      END

    -- check for French street type before address, if an
    -- English street type has not already been found
    IF (@Type LIKE '') -- only if not already found (prefer English type)
      BEGIN
        SELECT @FrenchType=TypeName FROM StreetType WHERE UPPER(TypeName) LIKE UPPER(@Temp)
        IF NOT (@FrenchType LIKE @Temp) -- try abbreviation
          SELECT @FrenchType=TypeName FROM StreetType WHERE UPPER(TypeAbbr) LIKE UPPER(@Temp)
      END

    -- if @FrenchType was found, get the final remaining token
    IF NOT (@FrenchType Like '')
      BEGIN
        SET @LastSpace = @NextSpace
        SET @Type = @FrenchType
      END

    -- assume it is the street name
    SET @Name = SUBSTRING(@Name, @LastSpace, LEN(@Name))

    SELECT @CivicNum AS CivicNum, @Name AS Address, @Type AS StreetType, @PostDir + @PreDir AS Direction
  END
ELSE
    SELECT @CivicNum AS CivicNum, @Name AS Address, @Type AS StreetType, @PostDir + @PreDir AS Direction
```

If nothing else, I hope this is a snippet of code someone finds handy! Although they don't particularly apply in my case, [here is a handy list of address edge cases](http://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/) from [@200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success).

Comment: This is probably covered by your French cases but I wanted to point out that in some American cities (San Diego) Spanish names are numerous.  Avenida Montuosa, Via San Marco, Caminito Suenos, etc.  And you may have spanish directionals as well.  "Paseo del Pueblo Sur".   So it is not just French names that you need to account for.

Comment: Interesting! We may not actually be required to fill out American addresses in this same way, but even so it should be fairly simple to add the Spanish types and directionals.

Comment: I can't follow the code, but just wanted to point out that not all US addresses have a "street type". My parents once had an address that was something like 20 Fairbanks. That's it, no street, no ave, no blvd, nothing, just Fairbanks.

Comment: @Donald.McLean Perhaps the most confusing aspect is that I couldn't find a way to find the last occurrence of a character, nor is there a way to split a string into tokens by delimiter. So, I was left to keeping track of the last space, and reversing the whole string to take tokens from the right hand side. Thanks for the comment, though! I think this should still work without a street type.

Comment: I would love to see the reference tables you mention.

Comment: @dnix Sorry for the late reply! In case it's still useful: US [Street Types](http://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28apc_002.htm), [Street Directionals](http://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28c2_014.htm) Canada [Street Types](http://www.canadapost.ca/tools/pg/manual/PGaddress-e.asp#1423617), [Street Directionals](http://www.canadapost.ca/tools/pg/manual/PGaddress-e.asp#1403220)

Comment: I'm curious what the motivation is for trying to decompose an address. [In general](http://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/), it's an impossible task, though the situation is slightly more sane in the US and Canada.

Comment: @200_success One particular government form has split fields, while literally every other situation in our application does not. So, the requirement is currently very specific to not even just Canadian, but to _Ontario_ customers.

Comment: @200_success That's a great link for edge cases! I doubt most of them will apply in my case, but thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Reviewing this code is essentially meaningless without a ream of test data to compare against.... and it would be really nice to have a debugger!

The REVERSE operations make keeping track of the data state quite complicated.

In general though, the code is formatted well, though there are a couple of issues:

- Your first if block `IF ISNUMERIC(@CivicNum) = 1` has a `BEGIN`, but I can't see the closing `END`, which I would have expected to find before the indent-matching `ELSE` in the second-to-last line. I would assume this is a typo?
- you have a number of `DECLARE` instances that are issued inside various other blocks. It is traditional to move all your declare blocks to be the initial part of your t-sql source... I am not certain whether this code-style is relevant though, but `DECLARE @LastSpace AS INTEGER` and others should be declared at the top.
- The code is just too much for this area. You need to break it down some more, or find a better algorithm. Tracking the string manipulations is a nightmare, and, frankly, I gave up... which means the code is not well documented, or simply too cumbersome.

My recommendations to you (in a priority of sorts):

- replace the 1-column system with a pre-parsed data system
- create a separate table with the data columns split, and have a join that your can access to see the fields.
- change the user requirmenets to not need this breakdown.
- Create a CDL User-Defined-Function (C# or something) that does the parse using a more friendly format, perhaps returning the data in tab-separated values.... and then splitting them in the calling SQL.
- go with what you have, it basically works.

Conclusion:

I figure your code is close to right, It may not be worth breaking it. Adding a CDL would be a pain to do, but the code for the parse would be much easier to manage.

My money is on the system-change to store the parsed fields.... ;-)

Comment: You can do debugging in Microsoft SQL Management Studio - it's really the only reason I was able to keep track of anything. Putting the data into columns instead was considered, it's just that it was a very hard requirement for a very small percentage of customers. Fixed the missing `END`, thanks.